# Angular router: promise returned from navigatebyurl is ignored

Tags: angular, promise, angular-routing

Using this code:

`this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');`

I get the following warning: promise returned from navigatebyurl is ignored. How and when would I want to handle the promise here?

P.S. I'm using this in AuthGuard's `canActivate`.

Comment: If you are not interested in knowing when that navigation completed, then indeed you don't need to do anything with that promise. If this warning is from IntelliJ, you [can get rid of the warning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41279095/5459839). NB: It seems odd to trigger a navigation within `canActivate`, which is intended only to return a boolean. I don't think adding such side-effects are good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the NB! What would you do, then, if you want to forward the user to a login page if they're not authenticated?

Comment: On second thought, it seems that is the way it is done, so forget what I said in my NB. Remains the warning you get: you can ignore it, since you don't need/want to do anything once that promise resolves.

Comment: Actually, I do! I would like to display a spinner before `canActivate` starts and remove it after it completes, since I do have an http request within that may take some time!

Comment: In that case put the code to remove the spinner in the `then` callback. Something like: `this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then(_ => { removeSpinner(); });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The navigateByUrl function returns a promise so you can use .then() method :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then(() => {
    // Do something 
});
```

Comment: That is certainly a solution, but what if I want just to make the navigation? Should I just call the `this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then()` to get rid of the warning? I do not want to add async/await as it would move the warning to the caller (who might not expect async call).

Comment: Here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234381/1662819) is another answer, I like better, which goes beyond the obvious