# How to wrap async/await in Typescript without errors and warning

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have a fetch call which is async of course, but I like to wrap all that in one or more functions, so the calling function doesn't bother.

This is what I have right now:

```
private async wrapFetch(url): Promise<void> {
    this.responseText = await this.doFetch(url);
}

private async doFetch(url): Promise<string> {
   return fetch(url)
      .then((rsp: response) => {
          return rsp.text();
      });
}
```

Now, I would like to call wrapFetch as if it is a normal async function

```
this.wrapFetch('some-url');
```

But, this line gives the following warning:

```
Promise returned from wrapFetch is ignored
```

I've tried to change the return type from wrapFetch, but that made it worse. Any suggestions how I can fix this or should I

Comment: is that a warning raised by typescript or by IntelliJ (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278900/intellij-idea-warning-promise-nreturned-is-ignored-with-aysnc-await) ? In any case the error message is referring to the fact that you do not use the value returned by the `wrapFetch` method, if you are inisde an `async` function a simple `await` before the call should be enough, if not you should probably add a `catch` handler to avoid any silent errors

Comment: Yes, a warning from my IDE, so its fine to ignore it!

Comment: Does my comment solve your problem then ? I can make it into an answer

Comment: Almost, I tried to reproduce it ([here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ljpuv3), but the flow is not right yet, the `console.log('f')` is still before `console.log('e')`. Is there a way to fix this, without using `async/await` inside the `doIt` function ?

Comment: If you assign the returned value to a correctly typed `var` it seems to be fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1iqahc?file=index.ts Not sure what the underlying issue is though (although I am almost certain it is  with the wai ts infers types and not with your code)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what modification to my example can fix the order in which the console.log occur ?

Comment: OK I read your comment a little too fast. To fix your problem you just need to make  all your methods `async` and add the `await` keyword before method calls (in the `doIt` method for instance...) event if you don't care about the result, just for the control flow, added them in  the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1iqahc?file=index.ts

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I hoped that it wasn't needed to add async/await everywhere, but with you answer and rethinking it, it makes sense!

Comment: You can avoid it by using a `.then(() => console.log))` inside your methods but I am not sure that this what you are looking for.

Comment: No, thats not what I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that a warning raised by typescript or by IntelliJ (cf
[Intellij Idea warning - "Promise returned is ignored" with aysnc/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278900/intellij-idea-warning-promise-nreturned-is-ignored-with-aysnc-await)) ?
In any case the error message is referring to the fact that you do not use the
value returned by the wrapFetch method.

To fix your second problem (the order of the `console.log` calls) 
you just need to make all your methods async and add the await keyword
before method calls (in the `doIt` method for instance...) even if you don't care about the result,
just for the control flow, I added them in the example stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1iqahc?file=index.ts